# golang : Unsolicited response received on idle HTTP channel starting with

Tags: go

this is my actual code :

```
func cURL(cURL string, follow bool) (*string, error) {
    var err error
    var resp *http.Response
    var req *http.Request

    var u *url.URL
    if u, err = url.Parse(cURL); nil != err {
        if logLevel >= 30 {
            log.Print("ERROR: ", err)
        }
        return nil, err
    }

    if req, err = http.NewRequest("GET", u.Scheme+"://"+u.Host+u.Path, nil); err != nil {
        if logLevel >= 40 {
            log.Print("ERROR: ", err)
        }
        return nil, err
    }
    req.URL.RawQuery = u.RawQuery

    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: 3 * time.Second,  //timeout connexion
    }
    if resp, err = client.Do(req); nil != err {
        if logLevel >= 50 {
            log.Print("ERROR: ", err)
        }
        return nil, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    var body []byte
    if body, err = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body); nil != err {
        if logLevel >= 30 {
            log.Print("ERROR: ", err)
        }
        return nil, err
    }

    var html string
    html = string(body)

    return &html, nil
}
```

same time print this error in terminal, i want to hide this :

```
2017/09/29 18:19:28 Unsolicited response received on idle HTTP channel starting with "HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out\r\nServer: AkamaiGHost\r\nMime-Version: 1.0\r\nDate: Fri, 29 Sep 2017 16:18:21 GMT\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-Length: 218\r\nExpires: Fri, 29 Sep 2017 16:18:21 GMT\r\n\r\n<HTML><HEAD>\n<TITLE>Request Timeout</TITLE>\n</HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>Request Timeout</H1>\nThe server timed out while waiting for the browser's request.<P>\nReference&#32;&#3
```

i want  to hide this error, not print in terminal, how i can do this ? Where im wrong ? i use this function for check large list urls if have specific keyword, the list is really big 50 milions urls.

Comment: One the servers you connect to is sending some unexpected data. There's not much you can do if the remote server doesn't work correctly. If most of the hosts are different, you could try setting `req.Close` so the Transport doesn't keep the idle connections at all. That however will slow you down significantly if each host is used many times.

Comment: @JimB my problem is not print this error in terminal

Comment: You would have to disable the standard logger, which it appears you may be using. If you use a custom logger, you could turn off the default logger output.

Answer (score 1):

That message comes from `http.Transport` within the `http.Client`, specifically [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/f2885263748364a2a7f4e0d47abd5095699cd39f/src/net/http/transport.go#L2242)

```
log.Printf("Unsolicited response received on idle HTTP channel starting with %q; err=%v", buf, peekErr)
```

Unfortunately, unlike `http.Server` which has an `ErrorLog` field for overriding the default logger, `http.Transport` always writes to the standard logger.

To prevent the message from being printed you can use [`log.SetOutput(io.Discard)`](https://pkg.go.dev/log#SetOutput) or `log.SetOutput(ioutil.Discard)` before 1.16. Keep in mind this will discard everything written to the standard logger. As JimB mentions, if you still want to log in other places, you can [create a custom logger](https://pkg.go.dev/log#New).